# SQL, how to check that the result of a select excludes all results where a string is matched from another table

Tags: sql, sql-like

I am new at sql and trying to learn how to do stuff
Please help me out with this query!

I have two tables

Table1 has a list of sentences, it has 1 column and 100 rows

Table2 has a list of words, it has 1 column and 5 rows

I want to select all rows from Table1 where the word "john" is found, but not if a word from Table2 also exists in that row. It is the exceptions list

How can I do this with SQL?

I've been trying some combinations of parenthesis but I have no idea what I'm doing:

```
SELECT "desc" FROM table 
WHERE "desc"LIKE "%matchedword1%" 
OR "desc" LIKE "%someotherword%" 
AND (SELECT string FROM exceptions) NOT IN "desc";
```

Help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT "desc" FROM table 
WHERE ("desc" LIKE "%matchedword1%" OR "desc" LIKE "%someotherword%") 
AND "desc" NOT IN (SELECT string FROM exceptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot parentheses:

```
SELECT "desc" FROM table 
WHERE ("desc"LIKE "%matchedword1%" 
OR "desc" LIKE "%someotherword%")
AND "desc" NOT IN (SELECT string FROM exceptions);
```

"AND" always has higher priority than "OR".

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't enclose your condition statement in parentheses, so write this query in this way:

```
SELECT "desc" FROM table WHERE("desc" LIKE "%matchedword" OR "desc" LIKE "%otherword") 
AND "desc" NOT IN (SELECT string from exception);
```